# Symfony2 FOS Rest bundle routing FileLoaderLoadException controller

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a very strange issue, with my Symfony2 setup.

I'm working on a restful webservice and would like to setup routing.

I have a fully working application and woud like to change my routing.yml config.

**Working configuration**

```
my_product:
    resource: My\Bundle\ProductBundle\Controller\DefaultController
    type:     rest
    prefix:   /
```

**When I change that to:**

```
my_product:
    resource: "@MyProductBundle/Controller/"
    type:     rest
    prefix:   /
```

I get the following error:

> Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException"
>   message="Can't find class for controller
>   "@MyProductBundle/Controller/" in @MyProductBundle/Controller/ (which
>   is being imported from
>   "/home/myproduct/domains/example/v5/app/config/routing.yml"). Make
>   sure the "MyProductBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded
>   in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make
>   sure the bundle path "@MyProductBundle/Controller/" is not empty.

When I change the type from "rest" to "annotation", the error disappears.

What am I doing wrong? I can't find it out and my searches lead to nothing.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried changing "@MyProductBundle/Controller/" to "@MyProductBundle/Controller/DefaultController"? The error is saying that the class for the controller is not found. Anyways, when you specify `type: rest` you tell the bundle to automatically generate routes from actions names of your controller specified in `resource`, so  `resource: My\Bundle\ProductBundle\Controller\DefaultController`  should work and I see no benfits from swapping the two routing you mentionned.\

Comment: Thanks for your help! I thought not mentioning the controller name is easier, because it saves me time by not having to add each controller to my router config. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: I don't think so, sir.`type:annotation` tells `FrameworkBundle` to look in your controllers files in `controller` folder of the bundle you specify in `resource`, and look for routes defined as annotations. But `type:rest` tells `FOSRestBundle` to look for the actions in a specific controller  and automatically generate routes from action names. These are two different things handled by 2 different bundles. `FOSRestBundle` implements this automatism but I think it  is not yet implementing this for all controllers in `controller` folder. I hope I am not wrong and wait for expert details form SO

Comment: Where are you at this issue? Am I totally right or there is something I am missing? Interested to know more

Comment: For now I've just leaved this as is, because of a lack of time and answers. Maybe I'll put a bounty on it in the (near) future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't currently import all of a bundle's controllers at once when using FOSRestBundle. [It will be added in FOSRestBundle 2.0](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/796). Import your controllers individually like in your first example.

[image]

Comment: Version 2.0 was released on 21st Jun 2016